# Connect WPF App to MySQL DataBase on ipage server

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I have a database on ipage server. I'm trying connect to the DB via Visual Studio 2013 to use data in WPF app but every time have an error "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.". What i must to do to access the DB?

using MySQL DATA Provider, WIN8.1

thx very much.

Comment: Max, I believe this error is coming from the MySQL data provider. It looks like there have been a few of these issue discussed on http://forums.mysql.com/

Answer (score 0):

Do you control the server, is it Linux based? If so check /etc/mysql/my.cnf - my own default installation had bind-address = 127.0.0.0 which was only accepting connections from the local machine. That's fine for PHP scripts, but not for remote access. I have set mine to 0.0.0.0 - accepting connections from anywhere. This works in the training environment I am running - you may want to tighten it up for security.